# IOS : Push notification on user defined time duration

Tags: ios7, apple-push-notifications, nstimer, localnotification, uibackgroundtask

My app should get push notification on user defined time duration (like on each Monday 11 AM).

So for that App have to check for new updates on server (on background) on user defined date and time, App might not be running at this time, but it still has to check for new updates on server. If any update found, server will send push notification for the same.

How can I implement time based background process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't let the server do all that? I mean, you will have to do a post with the selected date by the user from the app, and the server at the selected time will send a push notification to that particular user (you know what user it is by his token id). Amazon Web Services works like that for example.